# 2 different values from dropdown run same function, but only needs to run once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the scenario. I have a form that contains a dropdown with 4 options. If a certain option is selected then I need to insert an HTML element next to the label of the field. Basically I need to insert a FontAwesome icon that will display a tooltip. The problem I'm having is the FontAwesome icon will be added to the page as many times as one of the 2 options are selected. If I select "C40" then an icon is added, if I select "C60" another icon is added, if I select "C60 again another icon is added and so on. How do I prevent the change() function from adding multiple FontAwesome icons?

```
resModel.on( 'change', function(e) {

    if( resModel.val() == 'C40' || resModel.val() == 'C60' ) {

        $( '<i id="resC-control-box-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_3 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );
        $( '<i id="resC-cell-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_4 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );

        // Control box tooltip
        $( '#resC-control-box-tip' ).qtip({
            content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/awesome-img.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
            position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right center',
                target: $( '#resC-control-box-tip' )
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-blue'
            }
        });

        // Cell tooltip
        $( '#resC-cell-tip' ).qtip({
            content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/another-awesome-img.jpg" alt="Resilience C Cell Serial Number" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
            position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right center',
                target: $( '#resC-cell-tip' )
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-blue'
            }
        });

    }else if( resModel.val() == 'D40' || resModel.val() == 'D60' ) {

        $( '<i id="resD-control-box-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_38 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );
        $( '<i id="resD-cell-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_39 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );

        // Control box tooltip
        $( '#resD-control-box-tip' ).qtip({
            content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/img3.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
            position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right center',
                target: $( '#resD-control-box-tip' )
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-blue'
            }
        });

        // Cell tooltip
        $( '#resD-cell-tip' ).qtip({
            content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/img3.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
            position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right center',
                target: $( '#resD-cell-tip' )
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-blue'
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you please put a runnable code in fiddle and share the link?

Comment: Have you considering having icon in in DOM but hidden as the default on page load and simply showing it/hiding it based on dropdown selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Mike Brant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529853/mike-brant) I did consider this and even tried it once, but your comment made me think it over again which ended up being the solution I was looking for. Here's what I did and I hope it helps someone else...

Rather than insert the FontAwesome icon during the change event I simply added it once and then used hide(). Then during the change event I simply show() the icon. The result is just what I needed. One icon added and showing when the appropriate option is selected. Sometimes it's way too easy to overcomplicate and unfortunately I do it all the time!

```
var resModel = $( '#input_2_9' ); 
var resPlusModel = $( '#input_2_30' );

$( '<i id="resC-control-box-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_3 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );
$( '<i id="resC-cell-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_4 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );

var resC_ControlBox = $( '#resC-control-box' );
var resC_Cell = $( '#resC-cell' );
var resD_ControlBox = $( '#resD-control-box' );
var resD_Cell = $( '#resD-cell' );

resC_ControlBox, resC_Cell, resD_ControlBox, resD_Cell.hide();

// Res C Control box tooltip
$( '#resC-control-box-tip' ).qtip({
    content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/awesome-img.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
    position: {
        my: 'left center',
        at: 'right center',
        target: $( '#resC-control-box-tip' )
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-blue'
    }
});

// Res C Cell tooltip
$( '#resC-cell-tip' ).qtip({
    content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/another-awesome-img.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
    position: {
        my: 'left center',
        at: 'right center',
        target: $( '#resC-cell-tip' )
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-blue'
    }
});

$( '<i id="resD-control-box-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_38 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );
$( '<i id="resD-cell-tip" class="tooltip"></i>' ).insertAfter( '#field_2_39 label.gfield_label > span.gfield_required' );

// Res D Control box tooltip
$( '#resD-control-box-tip' ).qtip({
    content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/img3.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
    position: {
        my: 'left center',
        at: 'right center',
        target: $( '#resD-control-box-tip' )
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-blue'
    }
});

// Res D Cell tooltip
$( '#resD-cell-tip' ).qtip({
    content: '<img class="avia_image " src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/img3.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">',
    position: {
        my: 'left center',
        at: 'right center',
        target: $( '#resD-cell-tip' )
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-blue'
    }
});

resModel.on( 'change', function() {

    if( resModel.val() == 'C40' || resModel.val() == 'C60' ) {

        resC_ControlBox, resC_Cell.show();

    }else if( resModel.val() == 'D40' || resModel.val() == 'D60' ) {

        resD_ControlBox, resD_Cell.show();

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda lame solution...
Set a Variable in top of change function to 0;
Surround all the blocks where you are adding the icons and increment the variable inside the if statements only add an icon if the variable is still zero